# Capture the error from Remove-Item into the existing calculated property in PowerShell script to delete files?

Tags: powershell

How can I capture the files that cannot be deleted and their error message into a separate variable?

The below script can perform the deletion, but I'm not sure how to get the files that are still in use.

```
$totalSize = 0
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchRoot -Filter *.log -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object -Property Name,
                                   FullName,
                                   @{ n = 'Size (MB)'; e = { [math]::Round($_.Length / 1MB) } },
                                   LastWriteTime

    $totalSize += $_.Length
    
    $paramRemoveItem = @{
        Path    = $_.FullName
        Force   = $true
        Verbose = $true
    }
    
    Remove-Item @paramRemoveItem
}

$results
$totalSize
```

This is the error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\ErrorFile.BAK: The process cannot access the file 'C:\ErrorFile.BAK' because it is being used by another process.
At line:17 char:2
+     Remove-Item @paramRemoveItem
```

Comment: Use error trapping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using error trapping and custom objects:

```
$totalSize = 0
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchRoot -Filter *.log -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        # Remove '-WhatIf' to delete files
        Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop -WhatIf

        # You should try to avoid '+=' operations - please search Stack Overflow for rationale and alternate methods
        $totalSize += $_.Length

        # $Status populated with OK message
        $Status = 'OK'
    }
    Catch {
        # This block is only processed if there's an error in the `Try` block
        # $Status populated with the error message
        $Status = $_.Exception
    }
    Finally {
        # Output object for this item
        [pscustomobject]@{Name=$_.Name;FullName=$_.FullName;SizeMB=([math]::Round($_.Length / 1MB));LastWriteTime=$_.LastWriteTime;Status=$Status}
    }
}

$results
$totalSize
```

Comment: Thank you @scepticalist, yes, it is working, would it be possible to update the $totalsize to only count the file that has been successfully deleted ?

Comment: Just move that line inside the `Try...` block at the end. In fact - you dont need it at all, just do it after the script has run - I'll edit the answer